# Halting QGIS on startup until user is authenticated?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I have a custom made login form in Python, which launches on QGIS startup. But before the user has a chance to enter the credentials, the program starts normally, bypassing the form. From then on the user can interact with QGIS like the form isn't even there (which defeats the purpose of the form!! ).

Is there a way to halt QGIS startup until the user is authenticated?

Comment: How are you loading QGIS? In your form or are you loading QGIS first then showing the form?

Comment: First QGIS and then the form

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. All I had to do was `QDialog.setModal(true)` so the user can't interact with QGIS before interacting with the form (logging in) and `QDialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` so the user can't close the form

Answer (score -3):

*emphasized text*You must call the method run on def **init**(self, iface): it works well try it...i hope it'll help!