# How to programmatically interrupt QGIS initialization and startup

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm wondering how to interrupt the initialization of QGIS 2.0 on Windows XP before start up. I've put a dialog in one of my plugins that shows up on start up. However, I'd like to make a quit button that closes QGIS if desired by user.

I've tried two ways without success:

1. This gives me an error for loading the plugin due to sys.exit(), so it doesn't successfully close QGIS:

   ```
   result = self.dlg.exec_()
   if result == 1:
       self.doStuff()
   else:
       sys.exit()
   ```
2. This causes QGIS to crash--which successfully closes the program, but really not in the way I'd like it to:

   ```
   result = self.dlg.exec_()
   if result == 1:
       self.doStuff()
   else:
       QgsApplication.exitQgis()
   ```

I've been wondering about this second situation. In the case that I don't find a better solution, what risks may I be taking if I let QGIS crash repeatedly on purpose?

I've taken a look at this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86381/halt-qgis-on-startup), but it only interrupts the start up until a user succeeds to authenticate. I'm trying to interrupt start up by choice of user who clicks a "Quit" button before QGIS even finishes setting up.